# How to parse multiple sql statements with Calcite

Tags: apache-calcite, sql-parser

I want to know how to parse multiple statements in one string.

sqlparser.parseStmt() can only parse one statement.

For example, I have one string:

```
Create Table tbl1(id bigint); Select * from tbl1;
```

How to split the string to two SQL statements.

I expect to get a list of SqlNode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseStmtList()`, a method of the class `SqlParser` ([reference](https://calcite.apache.org/javadocAggregate/org/apache/calcite/sql/parser/SqlParser.html#parseStmtList())). It returns a `SqlNodeList`.